# Magento store optimization?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, optimization, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am facing problem the total number of request send to server is 223 which is huge and due to which loading time is 13 seconds 
How can I reduce number of elements
I have merged and minify JS and css

Comment: please show gtmetrix or magento profiler data

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/13.251.235.211/yLCtpwwG   @MagenX

Answer (score 1):

am i right that your server in SG (Singapore)??
too far for Swedish domain.

anyway testing from Singapore it fully loads in 4 seconds.
with TTFB ~400ms

but First Paint is 2 seconds

you can try to:

- relax css and javascript files (unmerge) to load asynchronously by file.
- compress slider images

223 files requests are ok.

and if you add https it will be little bit faster, due to http2.